# How to reset WPF progress bar?

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, reset

I'm testing a WPF progress bar and trying to reset it to its initial state, but it doesn't work.

```
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(200.0, duration);
myProgress.IsIndeterminate = true;
myProgress.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation);
myProgress.Value = 0;
```

Before animation, the progress bar is static (no animation).
After animation, the progress bar color is now light gray (lighter than before) with a brightening flash effect.

When commenting duration and double animation, the progress bar remains static. I see there's something to do with this double animation.

```
//Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
//DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(200.0, duration);
myProgress.IsIndeterminate = true;
//myProgress.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation);
myProgress.Value = 10;
myProgress.Value = 0;
```

How can I solve this DoubleAnimation issue? What am I missing here?

Comment: here's the video for whom has the same problem http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrgdcsHDHRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this thread:

[How to stop an animation in C# / WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298/how-to-stop-an-animation-in-c-wpf)

Comment: Yes I was there. I'm not using StoryBoard, but just c# code to test if this gray glow effect disappears.

Comment: Indeed it's a problem with OS

Answer (score 0):

Use this form of the DoubleAnimation instead

```
DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(0,200, duration);
```

Where you explicitly set both a from and too value rather than just a destination value.

Code:

Within the window ctor:

```
myProgress.Maximum = 100; myProgress.Minimum = 0;
```

Then say in a button click handler

```
myProgress.IsIndeterminate = false; //shouldn't really need this PB oddity
myProgress.IsIndeterminate = true;
myProgress.Value = 0;

Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(0,200, duration);

myProgress.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation);
```

The PB is in a StackPanel, xaml is

```
<ProgressBar Name="myProgress" Height="20"></ProgressBar>
```

This was initially tested on XP but see below

For a Win 7 solution please see here

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523217/wpf-windows-7-disable-default-progress-bar-glow-animation)

Comment: Ok, but the gray flashing glow effect doesn't go away. It's still there.

Comment: I am having trouble reproducing the glow effect you talk about. Have you set any other values elsewhere on the ProgressBar?

Comment: The  other thing to try is in your code toggle the IsIndeterminate to false then in the next line set it back to true, does that help?

Comment: I already uploaded the video on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQtGA_AW05U
you can see it in a few minutes. Progress bar is with its default values (I have not changed its properties).

Comment: Ok I will check it out once Youtube have processed it.

Comment: I see the effect, I am somewhat mystified - looks like it is not resetting a style - what OS are you running this on I am using XP?

Comment: Just tried this on Windows 7 - I don't like that glow - see this post which appears to solve it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523217/wpf-windows-7-disable-default-progress-bar-glow-animation

Comment: Thank you Andrew, perhaps we should sent it to Visual Studio 2010 team?!

Comment: You are welcome - yes good idea - Just added an update to my answer. I have already reported another issue with the dreaded PB where you cannot reset the max values http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852647/is-this-wpf-progressbar-odd-render-behaviour-a-bug