# Attach event handlers to controls within a data template

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, progress-bar

I have a list box in WPF which displays the status of a number of worker threads. Included in the display is a progress bar.

It turns out that progress bars have an issue (defect?): the "Maximum" value is a dependency property, but the progress bar does not update when this property changes.

Somebody encounted a similar problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655780/progressbar-not-updating-on-change-to-maximum-through-binding). The suggested solution is to add a handler to the progress bar that deals with the dependency property changing.

But my progress bar is created by the WPF framework through a data template. (See code below) How could I attach a handler to these dynamically created progress bars?

Or, is there another way to solve this problem?

```
             <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateTransferWorker">
                <Border Style="{StaticResource TransferWorker}" Height="Auto">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ItemHeader}">Transfer Worker</TextBlock>

                             <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FieldValue}" Text="{Binding StatusDescription}" />
                           <!-- Note that the maximum comes from a changing property. -->
                            <ProgressBar 
                                    Margin="6, 3, 6, 3" 
                                    Height="12"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    Maximum="{Binding ServerJob.FileSize, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                    Value="{Binding BytesUploaded, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

---

**Later Edit**

It turns out that it's not as simple as the Maximum binding value being broken, because there are working examples where progress bars dynamically updates perfectly well.

It wasn't an INotifyPropertyChanged issue. I was notifying of any changes to the ServerJob property, (but not the ServerJob.FileSize property which is constant for each server job.) I also put a breakpoint on ServerJob.FileSize.get, and the framework was indeed querying the filesize in response to the property changed notification.

I also added two TextBlocks to the control, bound to ServerJob.FileSize and BytesUploaded respectively. And they updated exactly as they should.

But for some reason, as soon as the BytesUploaded value became non-zero the progress bar would zoom to 100%.

I've worked around the problem by adding a new property "PercentageComplete" which calculates the progress, and that way I can keep the maximum at a constant value of 100.

Comment: This is strange - I *can* update the progress bar by changing the value `Maximum` is bound from. Are you raising PropertyChanged in the setter? What .NET version are you using?

Comment: You can download my test project if you want to see it working - https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxSAZ9JlU2w9ZmUzZGE0OGEtYTk3Yy00NWEzLWJjYTktMmQzOTY4YzY4ZGYz&hl=en.

Comment: @Andrew possibly you just have a typo in your binding - I assume the correct binding path might be ServerJob.FileSize instead of SeverJob.FileSize.

Comment: @Greg Sansom - Yep, binding the Maximum value works in that example. I'll have to investigate the bug further. I've updated the question now.

Comment: @Andrew: Sounds like you might have missed something simple. If you want to email me the code I can have a look - maybe you can reduce it to something that isn't commercially sensitive...

Comment: @Andrew: I don't suppose you get any binding errors in the Output console when you run the code?

Answer (score 1):

I tried creating an application with a `ProgressBar` in a `DataTemplate` whose `Maximum` is bound to a changing property. Like Greg Sansom i do not encounter any problem, i suppose you did not implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in the class which contains the property you bound to, doing so should be the easiest solution to the problem.

Comment: Hmmm. I wrote a simpler test application, and you're write, it works. I had implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for the "ServerJob" property. (Not for the ServerJob.FileSize property as that value constant for each server job.) I also put a break point on the getter for FileSize, and the WPF framework is indeed querying it. Which leaves us at a loss as to why I'm getting the bug.